# Can we block a SE user from looking at our profile and answering on our question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, privacy, profile-page

If someone think they got a stalker and want to block them on SE just like we can block someone on facebook.

Comment: Can we just close this whole thread now? I think we have all moved on and it doesn't really help anybody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are getting answers that you think are offensive, noise or spam, flag them for moderator attention. If we see the same user repeatedly doing this we will take appropriate action.

If someone is stalking you by giving valid answers there is nothing we can really do about this, other than take pity on them.

Comment: its just like, I asked few questions that were been asked to improve my concepts but I seen few answers that were straight copied from some blog without any reference or any changes made to them.
because these questions were related to concepts I was expecting answers based on one individual understandings not someone go-ogling and pasting someone else content without copying as I am afraid there is any topic that isn't already explained and cant b find on google except unique environment based scenarios, I hope I made my point clear enough :)

Comment: If you think content has been copy/pasted from someone else's blog without permission that is plagiarism. That is quite a serious accusation and you can flag it with a link to the original content. If it is pasted from their own blog, that is fine as long as they indicate that it is a link to their own blog or web site.

Comment: +1 great answer.

Answer (score 2):

So what we have is a personal disagreement. At the moment I imagine you're both feeling a bit put out by the community's response, and with each other.

Rehashing how we got here will not help, at this point you both need to take a step back and try to make something constructive of the situation:

If you feel you've been cheated out of reputation (by answer deletion or downvotes) then make a special effort to earn it back: You've then undone what damage you feel the other has caused.

I think you both have something of value to bring to the site, and I'd hate to see either or both of you leave. No-one's perfect; neither you, the other guy, nor me.

Now go be awesome, and forget this troublesome moment.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why I am getting the stick, I had one question that I copied and pasted, 1 ffs. All others are my own and come with links.

Plus that one I did post I reposted but it was in my own words! so i dont see why it got removed.

How am I farming? I am a sharepoint developer working within an international company. Its not my fault that timeToThine got upset I marked him down. Just look at what I marked him down for and you will see for yourselfs it was totally ohnest marking!

I have an msdn account and neva had this problem before I dont get why ppl get upset for 1) ohnest marking and 2) helping others. When a mod said I need to change the post as it was copy paste so I did and added it back in

and with him saying about his posts well I can tell you he has done a copy past job too as i dont belive he knows those answers! is that fair? no I didnt complain and flag it up!

Comment: Please see my answer: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/693/1529

Comment: Hi, yes I agree with you and will continue to do as im doing, if I belive a user has an answer that I know is wrong then I will mark them down and the opposite too :) I didnt mean any offence to anyone and didnt see why he got upset through an ohnest reply! for future reference I will do better!